# Natural Deduction Proof with Many Assumptions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

[image]

Above is this problem I am trying to solve. Wanted to see if my logic is correct with the hand drawn items on the left and my typed(red) rules are accurate to what it's saying on the left.

Also, don't know what lines to reference at the bottom. I don't know why $c \lor d$ would be false on line 17 but I know $\lnot$ elimination is the only way to draw false from something. Same with the $\lnot$ introduction on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at each rectangle (e.g. 5-8). Line 9 is the negation of line 5.

Similarly line 4 should be the negation of line 18.

Then the lines for $\neg$ elim and intro should become clear.

For line 7, $\lor$ intro only has one argument.